# jQuery Mobile: Closing a dialog navigates back to the wrong page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a form that when posted redirects to another page. This page then presents a series of links, each one opening a dialog box.

My issue is that when I close a dialog box jQuery mobile navigates back to the wrong URL - not to the one from where the dialog was called, but the one before.

Here's some code:

The page that is served through the form redirect manually specifies the URL as it is the product of a redirect.

```
<div data-role="page" data-url="/call/StockQuestions">
```

When on this page the URL looks as follows:

```
http://localhost:60887/#/call/StockQuestions
```

The link to the dialog looks as follows:

```
<a href="/Call/EditStockSummary/529" data-rel="dialog" class="ui-link">Set Stock Detail</a>
```

Clicking this opens a form up. When I click Cancel jQuery Mobile navigates back to:

```
http://localhost:60887/#/Call
```

Anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the HTML for the Cancel button?

Comment: I cannot replicate with default Dialog window close icon (little cross). Are you using the latest beta version?

Comment: is Call and call different? and if so - why do you do that? The problem is probably not in the code you posted here. Try putting it up somewhere and post a link.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to the most recent version of JQuery Mobile. I had similar issues and an update sorted it.